# TableEntity is being saved only partially in auzre storage table

Tags: azure, groovy, azure-table-storage

I am seeing a very weird behavior with saving of table entity in azure storage table. My entity definition looks like this :

```java
#File name is BatchJobRunTableEntity.java
package com.affinnova.batchJobs.db;

import com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceEntity;
import groovy.json.JsonOutput;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

public class BatchJobRunTableEntity extends TableServiceEntity {

    public BatchJobRunTableEntity(String jobId, String taskId) {
        this.partitionKey = jobId;
        this.rowKey = taskId;
    }

    public BatchJobRunTableEntity() {
    }

    public String accountId;
    public String jobId;
    public String taskId;
    public String referenceKeys;
    public String meta;
    public String task;
    public String batchServiceIdentifier;
    public String clientGroupId;
    public String state;
    public String createdBy;
    public String lastUpdatedBy;
    public Date dateCreated;
    public Date lastUpdated;

    public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public String getAccountId() {
        return this.accountId;
    }

    public void setJobId(String jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
    }

    public String getJobId() {
        return this.jobId;
    }

    public void setTaskId(String taskId) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }

    public void setTaskId(ObjectId taskId) {
        this.taskId = String.valueOf(taskId);
    }

    public String getTaskId() {
        return this.taskId;
    }

    public void setReferenceKeys(String referenceKeys) {
        this.referenceKeys = referenceKeys;
    }

    public void setReferenceKeys(Map referenceKeys) {
        this.setReferenceKeys(JsonOutput.toJson(referenceKeys));
    }

    public String getReferenceKeys() {
        return this.referenceKeys;
    }

    public void setMeta(String meta) {
        this.meta = meta;
    }

    public void setMeta(Map meta) {
        this.setMeta(JsonOutput.toJson(meta));
    }

    public String getMeta() {
        return this.meta;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public void setTask(Map task) {
        this.setTask(JsonOutput.toJson(task));
    }

    public String getTask() {
        return this.task;
    }

    public void setBatchServiceIdentifier(String batchServiceIdentifier) {
        this.batchServiceIdentifier = batchServiceIdentifier;
    }

    public String getBatchServiceIdentifier() {
        return this.batchServiceIdentifier;
    }

    public void setClientGroupId(String clientGroupId) {
        this.clientGroupId = clientGroupId;
    }

    public String getClientGroupId() {
        return this.clientGroupId;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return this.createdBy;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedBy(String lastUpdatedBy) {
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return this.lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return this.dateCreated;
    }

    public void setLastUpdated(Date lastUpdated) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdated() {
        return this.lastUpdated;
    }
}
```

My application is in groovy and I found that groovy classes do not play well with entity objects so I created a java class instead. Now everything except for "referenceKeys" gets stored in the table. Initially I thought it might have been the data, but even when I set same data to  "referenceKeys", "meta", only meta gets stored but the referenceKeys is just rejected. I have set the debug point to make sure the data was set as well.

Here is an example:

```
    BatchJobRunTableEntity batchJobRunTableEntityTmp = new BatchJobRunTableEntity("jobA", "taskA")
    batchJobRunTableEntityTmp.setTaskId("taskA")
    batchJobRunTableEntityTmp.setReferenceKeys(["keyA": "a", "keyB": "b"])
    batchJobRunTableEntityTmp.setMeta(["keyA": "a", "keyB": "b"])
    TableResult resultt = cloudTable.execute(TableOperation.insert(batchJobRunTableEntityTmp))
```

Its almost like referenceKeys is not even defined in the Entity.

[image]

I am in java 7 and using this dependency : 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:7.0.0'

**UPDATE**
Found out that it was because of method overloading, I had two flavors of setters one for string and another for map. If I remove the overloaded method for map, things worked which still doesn't explain why it would have worked for "meta" but not for "referenceKeys" - minor bump but a workable thing.

```java
    #HAD TO REMOVE THESE METHODS

    public void setMeta(Map meta) {
        this.setMeta(JsonOutput.toJson(meta));
    }

    public void setReferenceKeys(Map referenceKeys) {
        this.setReferenceKeys(JsonOutput.toJson(referenceKeys));
    }
```

Comment: I believe until you are not specifying all the field values (for at least one record) the fields won't be listed. But again this is not an error but a default behavior.

Comment: Hello, could you please post an answer of your solution? So it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it was because of method overloading, I had two flavors of setters one for string and another for map. If I remove the overloaded method for map, things worked which still doesn't explain why it would have worked for "meta" but not for "referenceKeys" - minor bump but a workable thing.

```java
    #HAD TO REMOVE THESE METHODS

    public void setMeta(Map meta) {
        this.setMeta(JsonOutput.toJson(meta));
    }

    public void setReferenceKeys(Map referenceKeys) {
        this.setReferenceKeys(JsonOutput.toJson(referenceKeys));
    }
```

UPDATE:

Had to remove this method as well, bit me right in production. So absolutely no function overloading is supported.

```
    public void setTaskId(String taskId) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }
```